# eslint rules that allows `let state = {`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

This is my eslintrc. It complains about 
`let state = {dataObjects: insurances }` not being correct.
What should I do to fix this? The code is running without errors otherwise.

**.eslintrc**

```
{
   "extends": "airbnb",
   "env": {
       "es6": true
   },
   "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
   }
}
```

**TextablesScreen**

```
   12 class TextablesScreen extends React.PureComponent {
   13   /* ***********************************************************
   14   * STEP 1
   15   * This is an array of objects with the properties you desire
   16   * Usually this should come from Redux mapStateToProps
   17   ************************************************************ */
>> 18   let state = {
   19     dataObjects: insurances
   20   }
```

Comment: I think question title should be changed, as it misguides. What if someone really wants to allow let in his project :)

Answer (score 3):

In React, `this.state` should be treated as if it were immutable. Using `let` for states makes no sense, instead you should add it as a *class property*:

```
class TextablesScreen extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    dataObjects: insurances
  }
  /* ... */
```

Or set state in constructor if you need `props` to populate default state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = ...
}
```

Comment: or set in `constuctor` using `this.state = ...` if you need `props` to populate default state.

Comment: If you want to update it later you should use `this.setState` [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html#state)

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks for the reply. Post it as an answer and I'll check it as correct. :-)